# Get time difference for each row in table

Tags: mysql

I am working on an online time card system and have ran into a road block. What I need to do is calculate in each row the `timeIn` and `timeOut` for a date the employee might clock in and out several times a day. I have a working query to find the total for the entire day but not for each individual row. I have included the structure of the database table with some examples of what I would like to see.

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| id | employeeID | date     | timeIn  | jobDescription               | equipType   | unitNumber | unitHours | timeOut  |
+----+------------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|  8 |          1 | 01/15/13 | 7:00 AM | Loaded sand in Jefferson     | Excavator   | 345        |      NULL | 9:30 PM  |
|  9 |          1 | 01/15/13 | 10:00 AM | Loaded sand in Jefferson     | Excavator   | 345        |      NULL | 12:00 PM |
| 10 |          1 | 01/16/13 | 7:00 AM | Loaded sand in Jefferson     | Excavator   | 345        |      NULL | 5:30 PM  |
| 11 |          1 | 01/17/13 | 7:00 AM | Loaded sand in Jefferson     | Excavator   | 345        |      NULL | 5:30 PM  |
| 12 |          1 | 01/18/13 | 8:00 AM | Backfill in Whispering Creek | Skid Loader | 297        |      NULL | 5:30 PM  |
| 13 |          1 | 01/19/13 | 8:00 AM | Backfill in Whispering Creek | Skid Loader | 297        |      NULL | 3:30 PM  |
|  1 |          1 | 01/20/13 | 6:00    |                              | Excavator   | 01E        |      7238 | 17:00    |
|  2 |          1 | 01/21/13 | 6:00    | Worked in Jefferson          | Excavator   | 01E        |      7238 | 17:00    |
|  3 |          1 | 01/22/13 | 6:00    | Worked in Jefferson          | Excavator   | 02E        |      7238 | 17:30    |
|  4 |          1 | 01/23/13 | 6:00    | Worked in Whispering Creek   | Skid Loader | 32SL       |      2338 | 18:30    |
|  5 |          1 | 01/24/13 | 8:00    | Worked in Hubbard            | Scraper     | 54C        |      9638 | 11:30    |
|  6 |          1 | 01/25/13 | 8:00    | Worked in Jefferson          | Dozer       | 4D         |       941 | 19:30    |
|  7 |          1 | 01/26/13 | 8:00    | Pushed Snow                  | Loader      | 950H       |       342 | 20:30    |
+----+------------+----------+---------+------------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Ok so what I would like to see is that for example the date `01/15/13` appears twice with different `timeIn` and `timeOut` values I would like to get a value back saying that in row with the id 8 there was 2:30 hours, then get another value back saying that in the row where id is 9 there was 2:00 hours. I would like to accomplish this with one query if possible.

This is my query to get the time for the entire day:

```
SELECT `employeeID`, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`timeOut`, `timeIn`))))   AS `totalTime` FROM `timeRecords` WHERE   `date` = "01/15/13"  AND `employeeID` = 1 GROUP BY `employeeID`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need this?

```
SELECT `employeeID`, TIMEDIFF(`timeOut`, `timeIn`)  AS `totalTime` FROM `timeRecords`;
```

You can use `PDO query` to query your database which returns result set as array of associative array. For better performance you can use `PDO prepare/execute`.

```
<?php
function getTimeByRow($connection) {
    $sql = "SELECT `employeeID`, TIMEDIFF(`timeOut`, `timeIn`)  AS `totalTime` FROM `timeRecords`";
    foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['employeeID'] . "\t";
        print $row['totalTime'] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is what I needed Thanks! I have another question if I wanted to access these individual times in PHP how do I retrieve them is it stored as an array with an index? So `totalTime[0]` would be first one?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to do something like this:

select employeeID, date, TIMEDIFF(timeout, timein) from timeRecords where date = x and employeeID = y